# Javascript generator doesn't yield new results

Tags: javascript, generator

I'm creating a generator function in React, to produce an insertionSort animation, step-by-step:

```
function* insertionSort(data) { // yield state of array at each step of sorting
  const inputArr = [...data]
  let n = inputArr.length
  for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    // Choosing the first element in our unsorted subarray
    let current = inputArr[i]
    // The last element of our sorted subarray
    let j = i - 1
    while (j > -1 && current < inputArr[j]) {
      inputArr[j + 1] = inputArr[j]
      j--
    }
    inputArr[j + 1] = current
    yield inputArr
  }
  yield inputArr
}

export default insertionSort
```

and calling the next() function on every button press:

```
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(insertionSort(data).next().value)
        }}>
        Insertion Sort
      </button>
```

However, only the first button press produces the expected results. Every subsequent press just reproduces the same thing.

I am confident the function logic is correct, as removing the generator syntax and just using it as a normal loop produces the correct results.

Am I missing something in how yield works?

Comment: You should update the `data` parameter, each time your generator yields the result, using setState.

Comment: Thanks for the reply dude. That doesn't solve it sadly, same results again :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every call to `insertionSort(data)` creates a new generator that starts from the beginning. You're repeatedly doing the first step on a new instance. You'll want to use

```
const sorter = useRef();

<button onClick={() => {
  console.log(data);
  sorter.current = insertSort(data);
}}>
  Start Insertion Sort
</button>
<button onClick={() => {
  console.log(sorter.current.next().value);
}}>
  Step
</button>
```